# Sqlite 3.7.15 Crosss compilation for ARM

Tags: sqlite, arm, embedded-resource, embedded-linux, embedded-database

I am using SQLite 3 for Database management in my ARM9 based microprocessor.

I want to cross compile the latest version of the SQLite 3 for my project in Linux (Ubuntu 10.04). I am using the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler` for development.

I tried to cross compile using following commands,

Downloaded the `sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.0.tar`
I extract it and then write the following command on Terminal,

```
sudo ./configure --exec-prefix=/media/8CCC8E9BCC8E7F68/SQLIte3/sqliteinstall/  --host=arm --target=arm CC=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar STRIP=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip RANLIB=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="-Os"
```

It successfully cross compiled the SQLite.

Then,

`sudo make` command.

It successfully run.

Now "make install " command.

It did not give me an error but when i went to the config.log file i found there is some sentences as following,

1.conftest.c:17:7: error: size of array 'off_t_is_large' is negative
 2.conftest.c:12:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
 3.conftest.cpp:23:28: error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 4.conftest.c:67:13: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

I doubt that weather it has been cross compiled properly or not.
I can not understand.

I inserted the library on my board it works fine but the problem is that the speed got very slow. I think there is some problem that i have not set any flags for the GCC compiler.

I could not find any options.How I can set the particular flags for the GCC compiler so that unnecessary features can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't try to do cross-compilation manually. Instead, use an embedded Linux build system that will do that for you, and automate the cross-compilation process entirely. My favourite is of course Buildroot (http://buildroot.org), but there are plenty of others (with varying levels of quality, complexity and features) : OpenEmbedded, Yocto, PTXdist, etc.

Comment: Thank You for your advice. But i want to cross compile using build Essentials.I went further. I found it is not able to get the right path for the compiler where it is installed. Am i Right ?

Comment: I'm sorry but you provide way too few details. What is "build Essentials" ?

Comment: Build Essentials is a utility to build any package.ok fine i got the solution an I have successfully cross compiled SQLite3.7.15.2 for my ARM9 based board.